# github 初回 clone 時の authenticity を、正しくとりあつかう方法は?

Tags: git, github, security

Github から Git で ssh で初回 clone するときには、「authenticity が確認できない」といったようなメッセージがでます。

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (xxx.yyy.zzz.www)' can't be established.
```

これは個人で開発している場合には何も考えずに yes を一回だけ押せば、後は大体なんとかなります。

自動化して環境デプロイをするときには、これはセキュリティ的にきちんと取り扱った方がいいのだろうな、と思います。また、このメッセージが発生することにより、自動化スクリプトが正しく働かない場合などがあったりして、やっかいです。

#### 質問

- サーバーをたくさんプロヴィジョニングする前提で、初回に出てくるこれを正しく自動化して取り扱いたいです。どのような設定ないしコマンドを実行するのが、セキュリティ的に推奨なのでしょうか。

#### 追記

アドレス形式は、 git:// の方式のものを想定しています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

初めての接続先だから相手の公開鍵をちゃんと確認しましょう、ただ生の公開鍵だと目視確認するには長すぎるから短縮した(ハッシュ化した)fingerprintで代替して良いことにしましょう、
というのがそのメッセージの意図するところかと思います。

従って、あらかじめ公開鍵がわかっているのならそれを取得して `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` に記載しておいてやれば良いのではないでしょうか。

```
ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

参考:

- [ssh(1) VERIFYING HOST KEYS](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#VERIFYING_HOST_KEYS)
- [Public key fingerprint - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint)
- ([GitHub's SSH key fingerprints - User Documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/))